# Discrete math, antisymmetric proof question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am so confused on this one question on my practice work. it's: Show that if R is an antisymmetric relation on S then any relation R' ⊆ R is also antisymmetric. I think how you solve it is if (x,y) are in R, they must be in R' since R' is a subset of R, thus (x,y) are in R'. To be antisymmetric x has to be related to y and y has to be related to x such that x = y. And since R is antisymmetric and x,y are in R and R' is a subset then x,y in R' follow the same condition of R making them antisymmetric. That's one way I think it's solved but not 100% sure.

Comment: @AdityaGuhaRoy *that part* is correct, but the entire proof is not. Your comment is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Mistake: If $(x,y) \in R$, then they must be in $R'$ since $R'$ is a subset of $R$.

This reasoning is not correct. If you see a black cat, you certainly see cat. If you see a cat, it need not be black.

If $(x,y) \in R'$, then $(x,y) \in R$ since $R' \subset R$, since $R$ is antisymmetirc, $(y,x)\notin R$ and hence we conclude that $(y,x)\notin R'$. That is $R'$ is antisymmetric.